# Prime numbers in Idris

Tags: idris

In idris  0.9.17.1,

with inspiration from https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers, 
I've written the following code for generating prime numbers

```
module Main

concat: List a -> Stream a -> Stream a
concat [] ys = ys
concat (x :: xs) ys = x :: (concat xs ys)

generate: (Num a, Ord a) => (start:a) -> (step:a) -> (max:a) -> List a
generate start step max = if (start < max) then start :: generate (start + step) step max else []

mutual
  sieve: Nat -> Stream Int -> Int -> Stream Int
  sieve k (p::ps) x = concat (start) (sieve (k + 1) ps (p * p)) where
    fs: List Int
    fs = take k (tail primes)
    start: List Int
    start = [n | n <- (generate (x + 2) 2 (p * p - 2)), (all (\i => (n `mod` i) /= 0) fs)]

 primes: Stream Int
 primes = 2 :: 3 :: sieve 0 (tail primes) 3


main:IO()
main = do     
  printLn $ take 10 primes
```

In the REPL, if I write `take 10 primes`, the REPL correctly shows `[2, 3, 5, 11, 13, 17, 19, 29, 31, 37] : List Int`

But if I try `:exec`, nothing happen and if I try to compile ans execute the program I get `Segmentation fault: 11`

Can someone help me to debug this problem ?

Comment: You should file a bug report on GitHub. There is obviously a compiler bug.

Comment: Done : https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/2290

Answer (score 3):

Your concat function can be made lazy to fix this. Just change its type to

```
concat : List a -> Lazy (Stream a) -> Stream a
```

This will do it.

Note: 
To get all primes, change the < inside the generate function into <= 
(Currently some are missing, e.g. 7 and 23).